# eclipse and tomcat,reading other project

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have a project in eclipse "dhanya" and have other projects also.When I try running the project "dhanya",I am getting errors.But in the error it all shows errors related to other project-"/hello1"

Eroors:

SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/RajD/Documents/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/hello1/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:11:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:496)

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/Users/RajD/Documents/java/apache-tomcat-8.0.36-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-8.0.36/webapps/hello1/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:11:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)

Comment: well problem with strtus.xml may be haven't define filter for struts in web.xml file

Comment: I had defined filter class,and it was working fine before

Comment: ok what is written on struts.xml : line number 11:72 .

Comment: and do clean and build and deploy war file from tomcat manager and then try